# About the alignment of stack frame, an example from CSAPP

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, x86

IA32 follow the convention of making sure that every stack frame is a multiple of 16 bytes long. Here is an example function:

```
char *gets( char *s ); //get String
void puts( char *s ); //put string to the screen
void echo()
{
    char buf[8];
    gets(buf);
    puts(buf);
 }
```

the gets and puts is just function calls, you can leave them alone.

the assembly code of this is as follws:(FROM CSAPP[computer system: a programmer's perspective])

```
1 echo:
2 pushl %ebp            //Save %ebp on stack
3 movl %esp, %ebp
4 pushl %ebx            //Save %ebx
5 subl $20, %esp        //Allocate 20 bytes on stack
6 leal -12(%ebp), %ebx  //Compute buf as %ebp-12
7 movl %ebx, (%esp)     //Store buf at top of stack
8 call gets             //Call gets
9 movl %ebx, (%esp)     //Store buf at top of stack
10 call puts            //Call puts
11 addl $20, %esp       //Deallocate stack space
12 popl %ebx            //Restore %ebx
13 popl %ebp            // Restore %ebp
14 ret                  //Return
```

the stack is like:

```
 ________
| old ebp|  4 bytes 
|________|
| ebx    |  4 bytes
|________|           ___
| buf[7] |            |
|________|            |
|  ...   |            |
                      |
                      |
|________|         20 bytes
| buf[0] |            |
|________|  ebp-12    |
|  ...   |            |
                      |
|________|           _|_
```

so why the compiler allocate 20 bytes instead of 24 bytes? Beacuse 20+4+4 = 28 is NOT a multiple of 16 bytes.

Comment: Should the return value be taken into account? But echo returns void.

Comment: No, but possibly the return address pushed by the call into the echo function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget the return address at the top of the stack! `call` pushes the current `pc` onto the stack before jumping to the target, and `ret` pops that pc and jumps back to it. Therefore, the stack is more accurately

```
saved pc
old ebp
ebx
buf[7]
...
buf[0]
...
```

which has a total height of 32 bytes.